# NET8 MAUI & iOS: error with AppCenter Crashes

Tags: c#, ios, maui, appcenter

In my `NET8` `MAUI` application, I added the packages for `AppCenter`. The application is working for Windows and Android. When I try to run the application on an Apple simulator, the building gets me this error:

> clang++ exited with code 1: ld: in
> /Users/enrico/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/LanguageInUse/1fa03704bb15e35c6f47a701d9d92131e3e0740198296a93338bb3c829bc9cf7/obj/Debug/net8.0-ios/iossimulator-arm64/linker-cache/AppCenterCrashes.a(MSACErrorReport.o),
> building for iOS Simulator, but linking in object file built for iOS,
> file
> '/Users/enrico/Library/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/LanguageInUse/1fa03704bb15e35c6f47a701d9d92131e3e0740198296a93338bb3c829bc9cf7/obj/Debug/net8.0-ios/iossimulator-arm64/linker-cache/AppCenterCrashes.a'
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
> invocation)   LanguageInUse   C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.iOS.Sdk\17.2.8004\targets\Xamarin.Shared.Sdk.targets 1559

I tried different `Target iOS Framework` but I get the same result.

Do you know if I can fix it? Do I have to remove the `AppCenter` packages (and this is so annoying)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underlying issue seems to be that the AppCenter NuGet doesn't support the ARM64 architecture in the simulator. As shared in [this MAUI GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/16778), you have to enter this in your CSPROJ file:

```
<ForceSimulatorX64ArchitectureInIDE>true</ForceSimulatorX64ArchitectureInIDE>
```